Ошибка Cannot access 'CandleChartClass' before initialization
Сама ошибка: 
предоставлю код по порядку:

ClassGraphReducer:
import { Charts } from '../models/Charts';
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const initialState: Charts[] = [
  new Charts(),
  new Charts(),
  new Charts(),
  new Charts(),
  new Charts(),
  new Charts(),
  new Charts(),
  new Charts(),
  new Charts(),
  new Charts(),
];
const ClassesGraphicsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'classes_graphics',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
});

export default ClassesGraphicsSlice.reducer;


Кусок файла Charts, куда показывает ошибку (указывает на стркоку this.mainCanvas = new CandleChartClass(this)) :
 import { IFlag } from '../../../modules/MainCanvas/helpers/DrwaingElementsHelper/GetHoverObjectOnGraph';
 import { ClassDrawingElements } from '../../../entities/elements/ClassElements';
 import { ClassIndicator } from '../../../models/Indicators/ClassIndicator';
 import { UnionClassesIndicators } from '../../../models/Indicators/DataOfConstructorsIndicatros';
 import { Notifications } from '../../../entities/elements/Notification/Notiication';
 import { GraphicType } from './GraphicType';
 import { getPriceChartWidth } from '../helpers/getPriceChartWidth';
 import { DateChart } from '../../date-chart/models/DateChart';
 import { PriceChart } from '../../price-chart/models/ClassPriceCanvas';
 import { FibonacciRetracment } from '../../../entities/elements/Fibonacci/FibonacciRetracment';
 import { CandleChartClass } from './../../candle-chart/models/CandleChartClass';
 export class Charts {
   drawingElements: ClassDrawingElements;
   indicators: ClassIndicator[];
   indicatorsOnGraphic: UnionClassesIndicators[];
   mainCanvas: CandleChartClass;
   dateCanvas: DateChart;
   priceCanvas: PriceChart;
   notifications: Notifications;
   constructor() {
     this.indicators = [];
     this.indicatorsOnGraphic = [];
     this.dateCanvas = new DateChart(this);
     this.priceCanvas = new PriceChart(this);
     this.notifications = new Notifications(this);
     this.drawingElements = new ClassDrawingElements(this);
     this.mainCanvas = new CandleChartClass(this);
   }


index файл, это вообще реэкспорт компонентов react, не знаю почему он указан в ошибке:
 export * from './ui/candle-chart/CandleChart';
 export * from './ui/crosshair-candle-chart/CrosshairCandleChart';



Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем ошибка ?
